# Heroku Postgres FATAL: out of shared memory

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I'm on the Heroku Hobby Tier Postgres. After a redeploy I got

```
psql: FATAL:  out of shared memory
HINT:  You might need to increase max_locks_per_transaction.
```

when trying to access my psql database.

pg:info shows

```
Plan:                  Hobby-basic
Status:                Unavailable, operator notified
Connections:           2/20
PG Version:            10.6
Created:               2018-07-02 18:38 UTC
Data Size:             1.38 GB
Tables:                78
Rows:                  4643980/10000000 (In compliance)
Fork/Follow:           Unsupported
Rollback:              Unsupported
Continuous Protection: Off
```

is there something I can do to resolve this myself from Heroku?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku routinely performs maintenance on the Heroku Postgres resource if you are on on the hobby tier. That is what happened in this situation. They are not obligated to notify you.

Answer (score 0):

It's also important to note that this should only cause a minimal amount of downtime:

> Maintenance windows are 4 hours long. Heroku attempts to begin the maintenance as close to the beginning of the specified window as possible. The duration of the maintenance can vary, but usually, your database is only offline for 10 – 60 seconds. [Source](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-maintenance)

If it is longer, this is likely not your problem.